# how to include external jar files while creating a jar file in linux?

Tags: java, mysql, jar, manifest

I have an external jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 under /Users/remy/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar . I want to create a jar file from hello.java which should include the external jar file as specified as well, where hello.java is dependent on the external jar file.

```
Users
  -->remy
      -->Downloads
               -->mysql-connector-java-5.1.26
                                          -->mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
Users
  -->remy
      -->Documents
               -->Hello.java
```

How to create the myManifest.txt and include the external jar file so as to compile and run them together?

Comment: Use an IDE such as eclipse and do it easily.

Comment: -1 @JunedAhsan if I could -- there's something to be said about learning how to do things manually before depending on a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Create a MANIFEST.MF that refers to the other jar in its classpath
2. Whenever you run the program, make sure you include both jars in your classpath.

That said, I think you should go back and [read a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) because you've made a few mistakes in your question.

- "hello.java" is not a jar file as you've said.  This is a java *source* file.  It will be compiled into a *class* file.  You can take this *class* file and put it in a jar file.
- You can't name your manifest file "myManifest.txt" AFAIK.  It has to be named something specific and be located in a specific place.  Read a tutorial to see the details on that.